# Splide.js get slide id on moved event

Tags: javascript, events, slider, splidejs

In slide.js there are several events which have a return value.

I want to read the return value of the moved event (newIndex, prevIndex, destIndex) and print it in the console for now.
https://splidejs.com/guides/events/#moved

I have this code:

```
splide1.on( 'moved', function () {
    console.log(`this.newIndex`);
} );
```

But when I slide the slider in console only an "undefined" keyword appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event parameters are not attributes of `this` but parameters to the callback function:

```
splide1.on( 'moved', function (newIndex, prevIndex, destIndex) {
    console.log(`newIndex`);
} );
```